# HTML: display: block - but element is still shown as inline

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm rather new to programming and stackoverflow has been very useful so far. So sorry if this questions might seem a bit simple to some of you, but I really can't figure this one out:

I'm using Bootstrap to develop my page and created a button which works just fine. Just below that button, I want the Facebook-Like & Twitter Button. This is what I'd like. But interestingly, the FB button always shows on the same line (hence left of the BOOTSTRAP BUTTON (that's how i named it in the code).

```
<a href="#Meinung" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg pull-right smoothScroll" style="display: block">BOOTSTRAP BUTTON</a>
<div class="fb-like pull-right" data-href="http://www.hafenkran-zuerich.ch" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
```

As you see, I've set the button's style to: display: block. But still the Facebook Button is shown on the left. I've even tried to set the BOOTSTRAP BUTTON within a , which are by default block elements. But that didn't solve the problem either. Any ideas?

Comment: isnt fb thing floated to left?

Comment: Have you tryed using css to change the styles rather than using inline stylings?

Comment: actually floated right: `pull-right`

Comment: try to give clear before fb button

Comment: add float:none!important; aside display:block; or remove class pull-right. you may use !important to overide bootstraps rules if needed.

Comment: To elaborate on the points that some people have made, the `pull-right` class adds `float: right` to the element.

Floating an element removes it from the document structure and changes the display style to inline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the `pull-right` class from both the Bootstrap button and Facebook button.

That class is causing both elements to be floated right, which is why they are displayed next to one another.

Here is a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JkD8g/

If however you need to leave the `pull-right` class on both elements, you can clear the Bootstrap button's float by applying `clear:right` or `clear:both` to the Facebook button.

Here's another Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Hudpz/